# How to replace a whitespace between a group of numbers with a dot or a comma?

Tags: regex, string, replace, numbers, regex-group

I have this group of numbers: 1 000 , 30 000 , 400 000 on some text files and it's a lot of them. I want to search all of this group numbers and add between them a dot or comma , like this 1,000 or this 1.000.

I know I can find them like this : `\d \d\d\d`, but I don't know what do next to replace that white space with a comma or a dot.

Answer (score 1):

If you regex flavour supports lookaround, you can do:

- Find: `(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)`
- Replace: `,` or `.`

if it doesn't:

- Find: `(\d)\s+(\d)`
- Replace: `$1,$2` or `$1.$2`

Both will replace a space between 2 digits with a comma or a dot